# Extract word from a list of synsets in NLTK for Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, list-comprehension, wordnet

Using this `[x for x in wn.all_synsets('n')]` I am able to get a list `allnouns` with all nouns from Wordnet with help from NLTK.

The list `allnouns` looks like this `Synset('pile.n.01'), Synset('compost_heap.n.01'), Synset('mass.n.03')` and so on. Now I am able to get any element by using `allnouns[2]` and this should be `Synset('mass.n.03')`.

I would like to extract only the word *mass* but for some reason I cannot treat it like a string and everything I try shows a `AttributeError: 'Synset' object has no attribute` or `TypeError: 'Synset' object is not subscriptable` or `<bound method Synset.name of Synset('mass.n.03')>` if I try to use .name or .pos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about trying this solution:

```
>>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>>> wn.synset('mass.n.03').name().split(".")[0]
'mass'
```

For your case:

```
>>>> allnouns = [x for x in wn.all_synsets('n')]
```

The item at 23rd index is "Synset('substance.n.07')". Now, you can extract its name field like

```
>>>> allnouns[23].name().split(".")[0]
'substance'   #output
```

If you want only the 'name' fields of the synsets of 'noun' category in the list, then use:

```
>>>> [x.name().split(".")[0] for x in wn.all_synsets('n')]
```

should exactly give the result you need.

**Note: In wordnet, `name` is not an attribute rather it is a function!**

Comment: Well, I am not trying to get a single word, like I said I will gather all nouns in a list with [x for x in wn.all_synsets('n')] and then from that list I pick one element let's say allnouns[2] that happends to be Synset('mass.n.03') and now I want to extract the string "mass". I've seen that code of yours earlier somewhere but that searches for a particular word - not my case

Comment: One of us does it wrong as I don't think we understand eachother :) I am sure your code runs just fine but you're missing the point or I fail at explaining it. Where did you get "mass.n.03" from?

Comment: I have a list of elements containing all nouns generated with the above code - now my list is as follows: allnouns = Synset('pile.n.01'), Synset('compost_heap.n.01'), Synset('mass.n.03'), Synset('dunghill.n.02'), Synset('logjam.n.02'), Synset('shock.n.08') - how can I get only the words like "compost" or "mass" or "shock" from that list? I have done x = allnouns[2] and printing it will show "Synset('mass.n.03')" - that's great, now I want the string "mass" extracted

Comment: That's just an use case! After you make the 'allnouns', do you want to extract all the words and put it in a list again?

Comment: I have allnouns = Synset('pile.n.01'), Synset('compost_heap.n.01'), Synset('mass.n.03'), Synset('dunghill.n.02'), Synset('logjam.n.02'), Synset('shock.n.08') and so on 82115 items in it now. I pick a random number "rnd" 0 to 82115 and get allnouns[rnd] and I might get "Synset('mass.n.02')" Now, I want to extract "mass" in a string variable

Comment: It works! My bad, you're right - Just run the damn code! :) This worked: [x for x in wn.all_synsets('n')][2].name().split(".")[0]

Comment: I still don't get this part: wn.synset('mass.n.03').name().split(".")[0] because the only way I am referring to the mass.n.03 is by randomly selecting it from a list as you have done when using [2]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80442/discussion-between-faceoff-and-mario23).

Answer (score 0):

Using `Synset.names()` to get the canonical lemma name of the synset:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('mass', 'n')
[Synset('mass.n.01'), Synset('batch.n.02'), Synset('mass.n.03'), Synset('mass.n.04'), Synset('mass.n.05'), Synset('multitude.n.03'), Synset('bulk.n.02'), Synset('mass.n.08'), Synset('mass.n.09')]
>>> wn.synsets('mass', 'n')[0]
Synset('mass.n.01')
>>> wn.synsets('mass', 'n')[0].name()
u'mass.n.01'
>>> wn.synsets('mass', 'n')[0].name().split('.')[0]
u'mass'
```

But do note that sometimes a synset is made up of several lemmas, so you should use `Synset.lemma_names()` to access all lemmas if you're using the surface word form of a synset:

```
>>> wn.synsets('mass', 'n')[0].lemmas()
[Lemma('mass.n.01.mass')]
>>> wn.synsets('mass', 'n')[0].lemma_names()
[u'mass']
>>> wn.synsets('mass', 'n')[0].definition()
u'the property of a body that causes it to have weight in a gravitational field'
```

In the `wn.synsets('mass', 'n')[0]` case there's only 1 lemma attached to the synset. But sometimes there's more than one, e.g.

```
>>> wn.synsets('mass', 'n')[1].lemma_names()
[u'batch', u'deal', u'flock', u'good_deal', u'great_deal', u'hatful', u'heap', u'lot', u'mass', u'mess', u'mickle', u'mint', u'mountain', u'muckle', u'passel', u'peck', u'pile', u'plenty', u'pot', u'quite_a_little', u'raft', u'sight', u'slew', u'spate', u'stack', u'tidy_sum', u'wad']
>>> wn.synsets('mass', 'n')[1].definition()
u"(often followed by `of') a large number or amount or extent"
```

And to exact all list of words in wordnet, you can try:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> set(chain(*[i.lemma_names() for i in wn.all_synsets('n')]))
>>> len(set(chain(*[i.lemma_names() for i in wn.all_synsets('n')])))
119034
```

See [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)